How to avoid killing the wrong process caused by linux PID reuse?
I am trying to write a pkill-like utility that matches processes by searching for a certain string in /proc/pid/environ and kills them. But the matched process may exit before I can kill it and another process may take its pid. In that case, I will end up killing the new process. Is there a way to avoid this race condition?

@security_paranoid What do you mean by "tool"? I want to achieve something like if is_matched(pid) then kill(pid) and the problem is that the pid may be reused such that is_matched(pid) and kill(pid) actually runs on 2 different processes.

What is your actual end goal here? It feels like using a magic string in the environment to mark a collection of processes might not be the best solution in the first place. It would be both easier and more reliable to use a tool made for the job (such as a cgroup). If you're concerned about highly unlikely races like PID reuse, perhaps you should also consider more likely situations like a process accidentally ending up with the magic string in its environment and getting killed when it shouldn't be, or processes modifying their environment to escape the killer.

@TooTea My goal is to write a task manager that can start and monitor / kill the process it starts. As I want the task manager to be restartable without affecting running processes, each process it starts is moved to a new session by setsid, and I do not keep a living reference in the task manager. Instead, I use a text file to record the pid of the process. And I check whether the pid still points to my process by checking the magic string in its environment.


Reconsider what you're doing. Instead of searching and killing processes by brute force, look for a way to prevent whatever starts them from starting them. (For example, if it's an unwanted service, disable the service.)

Find out the maximum PID value and calculate the probability of PID reuse. Process IDs on Linux are allocated incrementally until they roll over, and kernel.pid_max is 2^16 in older distributions and 2^22 in newer ones, and your tool performs both actions at about the same time (a few instructions apart) – so in order for that to happen, the system would need to start 2^22 new processes without ever scheduling your tool's process to continue running in the mean time – that's pretty unlikely if the process runs at normal priority.

Upgrade to a recent kernel and use pidfd functions that work with process file descriptors, such as pidfd_open() and pidfd_send_signal().



Thanks, I think for my purpose I will just go with option 2 and ignore the risk as it is highly unlikely to happen.

"... the system would need to start 2^22 new processes without ever scheduling your tool ..." - Are you sure? What if an offending process starts with PID 1500. Then the system gets busy for a while, lots of processes are spawned and exit, PIDs climb, and finally roll over back to a low number. A few more processes, and the "next free PID" climbs a bit more. By chance, it lands on 1499. Then OPs tool starts, and finds PID 1500. However, the kernel interrupts it. PID 1500 exits on its own. Two new processes start, 1499 and 1500. And then OPs tool wakes up again. Oops.

@marcelm Still, 2^22 is a lot of processes to start and stop. How many would need to start every second or so to make this a problem under normal circumstances?

@Berend The entire point of my comment is that the "every second or so" part isn't relevant. The part of actually rolling over can take as long as you want, the race conditioning happening is merely unlucky timing ("current free PID" is just below "PID to kill").

2^22 is about 4 million, which is a lot, but it's not an unfathomable number. I just did a quick test and my computer runs through maybe 4 pids per second, which would hit 2^22 about every 12 days. Maybe a busy server with CGI scripts (i.e. one pid per request) might go through many more PIDs per second. (That said, even if your computer does regularly wraparound PIDs, you do still need to be pretty unlucky for this to happen)

@BenMillwood ah yes, you're right. I could have done the math myself ;-)

@marcelm while I agree that the system does not need to start that many processes during that very short interval, it would still require extremely bad luck for: (a) the process you want to kill to die between the time you get its pid and the moment you actually kill it and (b) another process to start precisely when that PID is the next available one, out of 2^22.

@jcaron Maybe, but that's not relevant. OP asked "Is there a way to avoid this race condition?". This answer asserts that the race condition could only happen if the system "start 2^22 new processes without ever scheduling your tool". I show that that assertion is false, rendering the answer incorrect. Additionally, the chance may be small, but if the operation runs frequently, some users may actually run into it. Such is the nature of race conditions. This is why Austins answer is better; it provides the tools to avoid the race entirely.

Consider perhaps that a pkill command might be especially useful to kill a runaway (perhaps unintentional) forkbomb or something like it, so it might be killing a lot of processes at once, which both increases the number of pids on the chopping block that could be accidentally re-used, and if you implement it as "collect all matching processes, then kill them" you start to have a more significant window for the problem to occur. (So... don't implement it like that. But maybe there's some reason you might need to.)

@marcelm "rendering the answer incorrect" is a very strong statement to make in light of i) one bullet point of three, which says "if you can live with the risk of an unlikely event you can do it this way" and, more pertinently, ii) the third bullet point already suggests using the pidfd mechanisms -- tl;dr the answer in context might be improved by noting that your scenario might also occur, but to call the entire answer "render[ed] ... incorrect" is, well, incorrect ;-P

@bertieb Fair point. But that second point from the answer is incorrect :P

If you’re running on a new enough version of Linux, you can use pidfd_open() (needs Linux 5.3 or newer) or open the directory for the PID in /proc (as a file using the regular open() function, this approach instead needs Linux 5.1 or newer) to get a file descriptor that is tied to the specific process referenced by a given PID at the moment the system call is made. You can then use pidfd_send_signal() to send a signal to that process. By first opening the PID file descriptor and then using that to interact with the process directory (instead of checking the files in /proc individually), you can close the race condition you’re worrying about.
But in general, that’s only worth it for tools like pkill. If you are just trying to kill a process that you are managing, you should be either using a proper process supervisor like systemd or runit, or if you can’t do that at least using cgroups, both of which do not have this issue at all.

How does this solve the PID reuse problem? pidfd_open() gets the PID as an argument which by the time the system call is processed may refer to a different process. (The man page example guarantees that the PID has not been reused because it is a child of the calling process and has not been waited for, so that it is still there, possibly undead. But that is not the use case of the OP.) From what I read it is not possible to obtain, say, the path of the process image from the obtained file descriptor.

It solves the PID reuse problem because if the process dies and is replaced between the pidfd_open call and the pidfd_send_signal call, the process won't be killed. (There's no way to use a pid FD, as far as I can see, to do the matching, but that's fine: the only way a kill happens is if the process is the same process throughout, so as long as you do your command line matching after pidfd_open, you'll still only kill the right processes)

Weirdly it seems like opening /proc/PID gives me something that works as both a directory file descriptor (so I can do e.g. openat(fd, "environ", O_RDONLY) to read the environment) and an argument to pidfd_send_signal (as documented in the man page, though I didn't try it), but pidfd_open doesn't give a directory file descriptor (openat on it seems to fail with "not a directory")

@BenMillwood Interesting, I was not aware that pidfd_open didn’t give a usable directory fd.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica If you first open the pidfd, then check, you know for certain that you did not send a signal to the wrong process because either the process referenced by pidfd is still around and is the same one you looked up in /proc, or it was a different one that no longer exists and therefore trying to send a signal to it will fail. You can avoid the second possibility by using the /proc directory for the PID to open the pidfd and then doing the comparison by using openat() on that fd to open the files you want to check under that directory.

@BenMillwood The process dies and is replaced not between pidfd_open and pidfd_send_signal but before pidfd_open.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica but you're selecting processes by checking something about their environ, and you do that check after you've pidfd_open-ed them.

@AustinHemmelgarn https://gist.github.com/bmillwood/99779237d80784ecf35426e641b7bb55 if you want to verify / notice anything incorrect I did

@BenMillwood I’m not an expert on C/C++, but I don’t see anything there that looks wrong based on the man pages. I guess it kind of makes sense though given that part of the point of the pidfd_open() function is to provide a way to get a pidfd for a process without access to /proc.


Is there a way to avoid this race condition?

Consider ISC DHCPd.  This software places a PID file in /var/run/dhcpd.pid or some such location (user-configurable, and default location is sometimes customized by operating system distributions).  To end the software, you can verify that file exists, and use: [ -r /var/run/dhcpd.pid ] && kill $( cat /var/run/dhcpd.pid )
That might not be foolproof, I guess, in some operating systems.  But PID re-use and guessability has been treated as a potential security hazard for years, so recent code may use rather random PID numbers.  The chances of PID re-use may be exceedingly small, and especially re-use within a matter of seconds.
